# Matching multiple regex one by one

Tags: regex, perl

I have multiple regexes. I want to match a string with regex1 first and if it doesn't match, then to match with regex2. On each match I want to update a common hash with the value.

```
$str = "%v:%{local}p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %D";
@regex = ( /\%\{[\-\w]+\}\w/g , /\%\w+/g );
```

I want to match the each of the regex on the str and update a hash. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what your common hash is - or what part of the regular expression you're wanting to capture is, all I can suggest is how to test each regular expression one at a time until you get a match. Put them in a loop, and then use the `last` keyword to abort the loop once you found a match.

```
$str = "%v:%{local}p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %D";
@regexes = ( qr/\%\{[\-\w]+\}\w/g , qr/\%\w+/g );

foreach my $regex ( @regexes ) {
    if ( $str =~ $regex ) {
        # update hash here
        ...
        last; # exit loop
    }
}
```

Gun to my head if I had to guess what you want to capture I'd suggest the follows:

```
$str = "%v:%{local}p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %D";
@regexes = ( qr/\%\{([\-\w]+)\}\w/g , qr/\%(\w+)/g );

my %words = ();

foreach my $regex ( @regexes ) {
    if ( $str =~ $regex ) {
        # update hash here
        my $word = $1;
        $words{$word}++;
        last; # exit loop
    }
}

# print out words found
foreach my $word ( sort keys %words ) {
    print( "$word\n" );
}
```

Comment: Getting error: Bareword found where operator expected at t.pl line 3, near "qr/\%\{[\-\w]+\}\w/g"

Comment: Yes, you have to write: `$str =~ /$regex/g`